# Does Dask run multiple filters on a bag in parallel?

Tags: python, dask

I am reading in many files made up JSON objects - 1 per line. There are many "Types" of messages, and I want to select a few to read into a few dataframes. The dataframes may have different structures based on the message "Type".

When I run the code below, it seems like Dask makes multiple passes against the files based on the number displayed in the dashboard. For example, if there are 1000 log files in the path, the Dask dashboard will show that there are 3000 steps to run. Is there a change that needs to be make it a one pass operation?

```
import dask.bag as db
import dask.dataframe as dd
import json

json_msgs = db.read_text(f'{FILE_PATH}/log*').map(json.loads)

# functions for filter
def is_type1(j):
  return ((j['TYPE']==1))
def is_type2(j):
  return ((j['TYPE']==2))
def is_type3(j):
  return ((j['TYPE']==3))


# functions for map
def get_type1(j):
  return (j['TIME'],j['USER'],j['INFO_1'])
def get_type2(j):
  return (j['TIME'],j['USER'],j['INFO_2'])
def get_type3(j):
  return (j['TIME'],j['USER'],j['INFO_3a'],j['INFO_3b'])


type1_msgs = json_msgs.filter(is_type1).map(get_type1).to_dataframe(columns=['TIME','USER','INFO1'])
type2_msgs = json_msgs.filter(is_type2).map(get_type2).to_dataframe(columns=['TIME','USER','INFO2'])
type3_msgs = json_msgs.filter(is_type3).map(get_type3).to_dataframe(columns=['TIME','USER','INFO3A','INFO3B'])

type1_msgs,type2_msgs,type3_msgs = dd.compute(type1_msgs,type2_msgs,type3_msgs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dask will generate one or more task to read each file, depending on the size of the file and the block size you choose for `read_text`. Further tasks will represent the following processing that you are wanting to do: filter, map, and convert. Sometimes Dask can *fuse* together sequential tasks, but in general, it is not surprising that you have more than one task per input file.